# Attribute lost with yield

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, yield

There is some code that I'm trying to convert from `IList` to `IEnumerable`:

```
[Something(123)]
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos()
{
  SetupSomething();

  DataReader dr = RunSomething();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    yield return Factory.Create(dr);
  }
}
```

The problem is, `SetupSomething()` comes from the base class and uses:

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod(), typeof(Something))
```

`yield` ends up creating `MoveNext()`, `MoveNext()` calls `SetupSomething()`, and `MoveNext()` does not have the `[Something(123)]` attribute.

I can't change the base class, so it appears I am forced to stay with `IList` or implement `IEnumerable` manually (and add the attribute to `MoveNext()`).

Is there any other way to make yield work in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the method in another method that does all required preprocessing:

```
[Something(123)]
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos()
{
    SetupSomething();
    return GetAllFoosInternal();
}

private IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoosInternal()
{
    DataReader dr = RunSomething();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        yield return Factory.Create(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right.  I checked RunSomething() and it does not appear to use the stack frame or attributes.  It's too bad I would have to split it out like that.

Comment: I think in this specific case I'm going to avoid splitting it and keeping IList since I'm not dealing with large data sets.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use iterators (yield) if you require the stack frame functionality.  As you've discovered, this rewrites your method into a custom class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, you can easily just rework this to:

```
[Something(123)]
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos()
{
  SetupSomething();

  List<Foo> results = new List<Foo>();
  DataReader dr = RunSomething();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    results.Add(Factory.Create(dr));
  }
  return results;
}
```

You lose the deferred execution of the iterator, but it will work properly.

Comment: Right, currently it's creating a list similar to what you have and I was trying to use deferred execution with IEnumerable/yield.

Comment: @Nelson: Then you either need to do this (better for maintainability) or split into 2 methods (better if deferred execution required), or implement yourself(I'd avoid - no real advantage) - unfortunately, those are the choices.

Answer (score 1):

Could you split your method up, like this?

```
[Something(123)]
public void GetAllFoosHelper()
{
  SetupSomething(); 
}

public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos() 
{ 
  GetAllFoosHelper();

  DataReader dr = RunSomething(); 
  while (dr.Read()) 
  { 
    yield return Factory.Create(dr); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yup, similar to dtb's example, just reversed.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like the problem is that SetupSomething is only looking at the immediate caller on the stack trace.  If it looked a little further up (caller's caller) it would find your GetAllFocus call and the desired attribute.

I don't recall off the top of my head, but if yield is creating a MoveNext() implementation only because your class doesn't already implement it, perhaps you can implement your own MoveNext, put the attribute on it, and yield will find and use your MoveNext()?  Just a wild guess.

Comment: You're probably right.  If I implement MoveNext, then I would be implementing IEnumerable manually, which would greatly increase the amount of code.  Valid, but not ideal in this case.

Comment: Generated methods like yield's MoveNext are becoming more common.  You'll run into this problem again in the future.  Too bad you can't do something to fix the root cause - the stack trace in SetupSomething.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing something, but I can't make sense of using an attribute here.  You might as well have written it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAllFoos()
{
  SetupSomething(123);
  // etc..
}
```

A whole heckofalot faster too.  And safer, you're dead in the water when the JIT compiler inlines SetupSomething().

Comment: It's actually SetupSomething(params object[] values).  However, it could still be SetupSomething(int foo, params object[] values).  In this case, SetupSomething() always has to be called, even if there are no params, otherwise RunSomething() fails.  I think it's a bad design, but it's what I have to work with.

Comment: I think I would actually prefer it more like this: SetupParams(params object[] values); RunSomething(int foo);  Like I mentioned, SetupSomething() is required only because it reads the attribute, but the actual params are optional.  RunSomething() fails if you haven't run SetupSomething() and read the attribute.  Seems very backwards to me.